# Question on convergence of sum(prime(n)/prime(n+1)/n^2,n=1...infinity)

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

According to WolframAlpha partial sums for

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28prime%28n%29%2Fprime%28n%2B1%29%2Fn%5E2%2Cn%3D1...infinity%29&h=1

(I actually used the Maple notation for the input)

sum(prime(n)/prime(n+1)/n^2,n=1...infinity)

seems to converge value-wise (looking at partial sums) in the vicinity of 1.12984...

Are there any references to such calculations using actual (known by now) prime numbers?

Comment: The calculation you have done is using actual primes.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde - It's WolframAlpha (not me) and its free version, which I am using, shows partial sums up to n=1281 without stating whether sum converges or not.

Comment: The sum is convergent, of course - Direct comparison test, see below.

Answer (score 1):

Of course we have the trivial upper bound
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{p_n}{p_{n+1}n^2}<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}.
$$
Hence the sum converges.
For better estimates for the sum we could use 
$$
\log n+\log \log n-1<{\frac {p_{n}}{n}}<\log n+\log \log n\quad {\text{for }}n\geq 6.
$$
or even better estimates, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1270814/bounds-for-n-th-prime).