# Is $\sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty}\left(\frac {1}{n}-\frac{1}{p_n}\right)$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

It is known that $$\sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} \frac {1}{n}$$ is divergent. Also, it is known that $$\sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} \frac {1}{p_n}$$ is divergent where $p_n$ is $n$-th prime number.

I was thinking what would happen (in the sense of convergence) if we termwise subtract these two series to obtain      $$\sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} \left(\frac {1}{n}-\frac{1}{p_n}\right)$$

Is $$\sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} \left(\frac {1}{n}-\frac{1}{p_n}\right)$$ convergent?

Comment: This might be useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1270814/bounds-for-n-th-prime

Comment: Hint: heuriustically you can use the approximation $p_n\approx n\ln n$ and see what the 'typical' term of this series looks like.

Answer (score 24):

Here's an easy answer that doesn't require heuristics or (much) number theory: first of all, note that $p_n\gt 2n$ for $n\gt 4$. (Can you see why?)  Now, this gives $\frac1{p_n}\lt\frac1{2n}$, and therefore $\frac1n-\frac1{p_n}\gt\frac1n-\frac1{2n} = \frac1{2n}$. Now just use the comparison test against the harmonic series $\sum_n\frac1{2n}$.

Answer (score 2):

Using the estimate
$p_n \approx n\ln(n)$,
we get

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=1}^{m}( \frac {1}{n}-\frac {1}{p_n})
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac {1}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac {1}{p_n}\\
&\approx \ln(m)+O(1)-\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac {1}{n \ln(n)}\\
&\approx \ln(m)+O(1)-\ln\ln(m)+O(1)\\
&= \ln(m)-\ln\ln(m)+O(1)\\
&\to \infty\\
\end{array}
$