Why is the limit in Willans formula for primes set to $2^n$?
We all know the enormous and tedious formula for primes by Willan.
I fail to understand why was it necessary to set the limit as high as $2^n$.
The equation runs into Zero's halfway.
Is this the only way? Or is there anything else that can substitute $2^n$?
Any help &/ clarification would be beneficial.
Thanks in advance.

Is the explanation in this YouTube video sufficient to your question?

It doesn't explain the significance of 2^n

And is there a way to replace it if I want to minimise thread time if I want to use it for python

The video does explain why $2^{n}$ is there, it is due to Bertrand's postulate.

However he also mentioned that in reality, $n^{th}$ prime is way smaller than $2^n$.

That I why a asked weather we can substitute $2^n$ by something else to increase efficiency, which Willan wasn't concerned about.

That video did clarify 1 part of the question. Thank you.

Better bounds for $n$-th prime (including uppers and lowers) were found by multiple authors, as you can see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1270814/bounds-for-n-th-prime
